# Uploading an Image using Swagger API

Tags: laravel, swagger, swagger-ui

I am developing an api using Laravel 7 and I use Swagger for API documentation. My issue is that I want to upload images using the Swagger API but it doesn't it only displays [object File] when printing out the images, so I can't upload them to the public folder.
My store method

```
/**
 * Store a newly created Products.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 *  
 * @OA\Post(
 *     path="/api/products",
 *     tags={"Product"},
 *     @OA\Response(response="200", description="Adding a new Product."),
 * 
 *    @OA\Parameter(
 *     name="name[]",
 *     in="query",
 *     description="Product Name",
 *     required=true,
 *     @OA\Schema(type="array", @OA\Items(type="string")),
 *   ),    
 *    @OA\Parameter(
 *     name="images[]",
 *     in="query",
 *     description="Product Images",
 *     required=true,
 *    @OA\Schema(type="array", @OA\Items(type="file")),
 *   ), 
 *   * )
 * )
 *
 */
public function upload(Request $request)
{

    $request->validate([
        "name" => "required",
        "images" => "required",
    ]);

    $images = $request->images;

    $product = Product::create([]);


    if(! is_dir(public_path("/products")) ){
        mkdir(public_path("/products"), 0777);
    }
    $id = $product->id;    
    $imageCollection = Collection::wrap($images);
    $imageCollection->each(function($image) use ($id){
        $basename = Str::random();
        $original = $basename . "." . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $image->move(public_path("/products"), $original);

        ProductMedia::create([
            "product_id" => $id,
            "image" => "/products/".$original,
        ]);

    });

    return Product::where("id", $product->id)->with("productMedia")->get();

}
```

How can I add images through Swagger API?

Answer (score 3):

Instead param with image, try to do something like this

```
/**
     * @OA\Post(
     *     path="/pet/{petId}/uploadImage",
     *     description="",
     *     summary="uploads an image",
     *     operationId="uploadFile",
     *     @OA\RequestBody(
     *         required=true,
     *         @OA\MediaType(
     *             mediaType="multipart/form-data",
     *             @OA\Schema(
     *                 @OA\Property(
     *                     description="Additional data to pass to server",
     *                     property="additionalMetadata",
     *                     type="string"
     *                 ),
     *                 @OA\Property(
     *                     description="file to upload",
     *                     property="file",
     *                     type="string",
     *                     format="file",
     *                 ),
     *                 required={"file"}
     *             )
     *         )
     *     ),
     *     @OA\Parameter(
     *         description="ID of pet to update",
     *         in="path",
     *         name="petId",
     *         required=true,
     *         @OA\Schema(
     *             type="integer",
     *             format="int64"
     *         ),
     *     ),
     *     @OA\Response(
     *         response="200",
     *         description="successful operation",
     *         @OA\Schema(ref="#/components/schemas/ApiResponse")
     *     ),
     *     security={
     *         {
     *             "petstore_auth": {
     *                 "read:pets",
     *                 "write:pets"
     *             }
     *         }
     *     },
     *     tags={
     *         "pet"
     *     }
     * )
     * */
    public function uploadFile()
    {
    }
```

example from here: https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php/blob/master/Examples/petstore.swagger.io/Controllers/PetController.php

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using the [L5 Swagger Package](https://github.com/DarkaOnLine/L5-Swagger). You may have to figure out how to add an annotation to allow **multipart/form-data**. Not sure how to configure that through the Package, but here is some more info from from the [Swagger File Upload Documentation](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/file-upload/)

Comment: Yes, I am using L5 Package. ok I will try to figure it out.

Comment: thanks @mchljams, that solved my problem.